# How to read multiple barcode reader?

Tags: node.js, zxing, zxing-js

I want to scan all barcode 1D in an image.
I'm using @zxingjs/library, i can scan 1 barcode but not all.
How i can do it with nodejs?
I know that there is an interface MUltipleBarcodeReader with 2 methods, but I don't know how to use it in my prototype.

This is MultipleBarcodeReader

```
import BinaryBitmap from '../BinaryBitmap';
import DecodeHintType from '../DecodeHintType';
import Result from '../Result';
/**
 * Implementation of this interface attempt to read several barcodes from one image.
 *
 * @see com.google.zxing.Reader
 * @author Sean Owen
 */
export default interface MultipleBarcodeReader {
    /**
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    decodeMultiple(image: BinaryBitmap): Result[];
    /**
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    decodeMultiple(image: BinaryBitmap, hints: Map<DecodeHintType, any>): Result[];
}
```

This is my prototype:

```
const {MultipleBarcodeReader} = require('@zxing/library/esm/core/multi/MultipleBarcodeReader');

//I read image with fs and decode it
//hints

const multipleBarcodeReader = new MultipleBarcodeReader();
multipleBarcodeReader.setHints(hints);
const multipleResult = multipleBarcodeReader.decodeMultiple(binaryBitmap)
```

When I run my prototype, it gaves me this errors:

```
const multipleBarcodeReader = new MultipleBarcodeReader();
                              ^

TypeError: MultipleBarcodeReader is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\awais.ahmed\Desktop\ZXing\index.js:27:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Thanks

Comment: You provided a lot of info, that's helpful! However, you might have saved yourself some time if you googled "javascript is not a constructor". Results include MDN's page on [`TypeError: "x" is not a constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor)

Comment: okay, thanks. MultipleBarcodeReader is an interface so how I can access to this interface and his method in my prototype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to decode multiple 1D barcodes according to this issue on their github [Multiple Codes in one image #346](https://github.com/zxing-js/library/issues/346). That issue is recent, so consider reacting there in that issue with a thumbs up emoji to show you want that feature. That TS type you found I think is a sign that they planned to implement it at one point.

However, you can decode multiple PDF417 codes using that library:

- [`PDF417Reader.decodeMultiple()`](https://github.com/zxing-js/library/blob/fc7b88ceca60524592888057d4a3c41bf100bd48/src/core/pdf417/PDF417Reader.ts#L92)
- [comment from maintainer](https://github.com/zxing-js/library/issues/346#issuecomment-716266086)